# Angular Directives VS Windows Phone Data Savings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8, angular-directive, ie-mobile

I have a pretty curious problem with my (a little bit complex) **Angular JS Application**.

On PC, Android, iOS, everything is fine, but **on Windows Phone**, with **Internet Explorer Data Sense Savings feature turned to "Automatic"** some **custom directives (created by me) are simply not loaded** most of the times.

If I turn this feature off, everything loads up fine.

This App uses RequireJS with RouteProvider and sometimes it fails to load some dependencies too. All of this in Windows Phone Internet Explorer.

On Internet Explorer PC (even simulating Windows Phone) everything is fine.

Some ideas on **how to disable Data Sense Savings on not loading my Angular Directives**?

Thanks!

Comment: Have  you got an error message?

Comment: Nothing, anything, the directive just don't load up.